# Can't have a conditional image source statement?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, volume

I don't know why but I get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

With this code:

```
private void volumeTracker_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e) 
{
    video.Volume = volumeTracker.Value;

    if (volumeTracker.Value == 0) 
    {
        volume.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/mutebutton.png"));
    }
    else
    {
        volume.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/volumebutton.png")); //Error occurs on this line
    }
}
```

This makes no sense to me seeing as it works, if I just set the source once (*for example if I removed the else part of this code*).

Comment: Please so some debugging with temporary variables to trace the null value. Something in that line comes out to null and only you have the project open and a debugger at hand. At the very least, put a breakpoint in and evaluate the expressions in the watch window.

Comment: Do you actually have an image "volumebutton.png" in that location?  If not, could it be possible that the BitmapImage is null, and therefore the `volume.Source` setter throws an exception?

Comment: Think I figured it. Seems to not work in the ValueChanged event, probably something to do with it not being able to cope with changing the source every time the value of the slider changes which can be quite rapid. The same code seems to behave Ok in other event handlers.